# nand gates inverter

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, digital-communications, nand

There are 2 ways to use 2 input nand gates as a inverter. I know one of them, which is make 2 inputs connected to one input signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fipig8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can someone tell me another one?

Comment: hint it's not if one input =0

Answer (score 1):

It's this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcVPY7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'd recommend replacing Vdd with "logic 1" as more general. At the least, the poster might be using TTL logic, which doesn't use Vdd (or at least it 's not usually called that, rather Vcc).

Comment: Yeah, fair enough @WhatRoughBeast. I considered both but looking back it's a logic question, not an implementation/circuit question.