# What is the best way to make an inverter from a NAND or NOR?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

As stated in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/307682/nand-gates-inverter), there are two ways to make an inverter out of a NAND gate, and similarly for NOR:

1. Connect the signal to both inputs.
2. Connect the signal to one of the inputs, and the other input to 1 (for NAND) or 0 (for NOR).

What are the advantages/disadvantages of each method? I've seen that the most common way is (1) but I've also seen that there's a limit in how many inputs can be driven by a single output, so my intuition says that (2) is preferable because it needs driving just one input.

Comment: Best way is awfully general when your situation is also general. It might be irrelevant how to do it unless you have some specific limitations.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I can see a downside to connecting both inputs to the signal if the logic family has low [_fan-out_ capability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan-out). That might have been a real concern back when TTL roamed the Earth. Maybe not so much in the CMOS era.

Comment: In some design the routing is more expensive if you need to connect one input to 0 or 1. I believe it's dependent on too many actual details to be answered generally. -- Did you consider different propagation delays?

Answer (score 3):

(2) is generally preferable because of the slightly lower loading of the signal, and a slight improvement in propagation delay.

Note that generally the two inputs are not precisely equivalent. The 'A' input here is slightly faster than the 'B' input because when the output toggles, the capacitance of the B transistor doesn't have to be charged (that junction remains at 0 V if 'B' is tied to logic 1.

In most circuits however, the speed improvement--while present--is negligible.

[image: CMOS NAND Gate]

(Image source: [Wikipedia - NAND gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate))

Answer (score 2):

Connect the signal to both inputs may be very easy for PCB routing. When the inputs are adjacent pads, you only need a very short trace between them, but you load the output of the gate driving with two inputs instead of one.

Connecting an unused input to 0 or 1 may be more difficult to route for PCB layout. You might need an additional via and some of the precious narrow space under the chip package. Using pin and gate swap you may move the input to a pad adjacent to VCC or GND, routing will be very easy then.

Answer (score 0):

One reason 1) (connecting the signal to both inputs) is not recommended, at least in the old days, is that it drives the ATPG (automatic test pattern generation) tools bananas.  Why?  Because the tool cannot come up with a stimulus vector set that allows you to isolate a fault to one input or the other.